# Configure bash_profile for one single terminal emulator

Tags: linux, command-line, .bash-profile

I am using a new terminal emulator. *Terminology* is the E17 default terminal, and it has a great command: `tyls` which is a "graphical" `ls`

I want to create an alias just for this terminal, because the command `tyls` does not make sense to konsole, rxvt or other terminals.

I am thinking in some kind of `if`-statement in `~/.bash_profile` to test if I am on terminology and then run the following command:

```
alias ls="tyls"
```

But how can I test if I am in terminology or any other terminal?

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terminology sets variable `$TERMINOLOGY=1`, so you can just test it

[[ $TERMINOLOGY == 1 ]] && alias ls=tyls